# Variance of random intercept in a linear mixed model (LMM) versus fitted random intercepts

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am struggling to understand the relationship between the variance of the random intercept in a linear mixed model (LMM) and the fitted random intercepts of the clusters.

Suppose the following model.
$$y_{ij} = (\beta_0 + b_{i}) + \beta_1x_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$$

Where subscript $ij$ denotes the $j^{th}$ observation within cluster $i$, and $b_{i}$ is the random intercept for cluster $i$.

I've got some data, and I'm using R to fit a model using `lme4` as follows.

`model <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 | observed_cluster), data = data)`

From this, within `summary(model)` I can see the variance of the random effect of 'observed cluster (Intercept)'. I interpret this as the $G$ such that $b_{i} \sim N(0, G)$.

In addition to this, I can use the `ranef` function to give me the 'conditional modes of the random effects' for each cluster. I interpret these as the fitted random intercepts.

However, when I take the variance of the outputted `ranef` values this does not equal the $G$. It is close (something like $0.6661$ versus $0.6546246$).

My question is why are these numbers different? Should they not be the same?

A hypothesis of mine is something to do with the model not fully converging. A text I'm reading gives the following as the 'mixed model equations', where $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ is the variance of the residuals.
[image: Mixed model equations]

With $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ unknown, the text describes some iterative process that starts with initial values of $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{R}$, solves the above equation for $\mathbf{\beta}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, which then updates $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{R}$. Repeat until convergence. The intitial estimate of $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ can be done using ANOVA, ML, REML, etc.

So, it makes sense to me that if the equation above does not converge fully, then we are left with the mismatch I described.

Another idea I considered is that if the true random effects are non-normal, maybe things break down.

Is this the source of the discrepancy, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two variances are not the same. Namely, the model is
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + b_i + \varepsilon_{ij},\\
b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_b^2), \quad \varepsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2).
\end{array}\right.$$

In the `summary()` method output, you get the estimated $\hat \sigma_b^2$, which is the variance of the marginal distribution of $[b_i]$. However, `ranef()` gives you $\hat b_i$, which is the mean/mode of the conditional distribution $[b_i \mid y_i]$, with $y_i = (y_{i1}, \ldots, y_{in_i})$. In general, $\mbox{var}(\hat b_i) \neq \sigma_b^2$, and actually $[b_i \mid y_i]$ are not identically distributed because they depend on the data of subject $i$.

Comment: Thanks Dimitris - Suppose that $y_i$ and $b_i$ are nearly independent. Possibly the situation this arises in is that I generate data according to the model in your answer, and $\sigma_b^2$ is tiny in comparison to $\sigma^2$. Then we would expect the marginal distribution of $b_i$ to be very similar as the conditional distribution $[b_i | y_i]$. Hence, would the two variances be roughly equal under these circumstances?